# Setting escapeXml flag true in jspContext through finally block : escapes every special symbols in every pages

Tags: java, escaping, jsp-tags, html-escape-characters, try-finally

My code looks as follows

public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {

```
    try {
        if (type == null ) {
            throw new JspException("type  cannot be null");
        }

        type = get_content_utils.extractAutoGeneratedKey(isAutoGen, type);


        getJspContext().setAttribute(EscapeXmlELResolver.ESCAPE_XML_ATTRIBUTE, false);

        } finally {
        getJspContext().setAttribute(EscapeXmlELResolver.ESCAPE_XML_ATTRIBUTE, true);
    }
```

}

I am trying to protect my code from xss attacks, hence were trying to escape special symbols used anywhere in the tags or jsps.
It seems like this escapes special symbols everywhere, but some places i still need to preserve the symbols like & £ etc.Is there any alternative way to escape special symbols where ever i required. some condition like that

Comment: The condition is the tricky part:how to judge when is the input actually safe to allow special characters(even though a specific set ,it may be)

Comment: That is the problem here, we can't simply add a set of characters to skip. Some pages may need to display but not everywhere. Is there any other way to handle this scenario?